# Strange L.E.D.-esque glare surrounding mesh (EEVEE rendering)

Tags: eevee-render-engine

When trying to work with a mesh, I'm noticing these crazy bright glares surrounding and shape-shifting around my object.

These glowy shapes take place only in the viewport shading mode of EEVEE. I would definitely like to render my animated object in EEVEE rather than doing it in Cycles.

I am working off of a 2016 Macbook Pro
 - (2.5 GHz Quad-Core Intel Core i7)
 - (16 GB 1600 MHz DDR3)
 - (Intel Iris Pro 1536 MB)

I've also attached an image for reference. Any help is greatly appreciated! Thank you!

[image]

Comment: Looks like a graphics glitch, likely caused by a problem problem with your graphics driver. What version of macOS are you using? Can you try the most [recent experimental version](https://builder.blender.org/download/) of Blender and see if the issue still occurs?

Comment: My MacOS is up to date (Catalina version 10.15.1). Are there any other things I can I do to troubleshoot my graphics driver? Is there a graphics driver reset I can try on my Mac?